# Ignore category in update form

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Im updating a category name, but i need to be unique and also case is the current record let it update, but it is not working my validation.

Example:

```
 $this->validate($request, array(
                'category'         => 'required|unique:categories,name,:id|min:2'
         ));
```

Comment: is this is server side validation??

Comment: @SoniyaReddy no this is patrick. (it is S.S.V.)

Answer (score 1):

From [`unique()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-unique) rule description:

> Sometimes, you may wish to ignore a given ID during the unique check. For example, consider an "update profile" screen that includes the user's name, e-mail address, and location. Of course, you will want to verify that the e-mail address is unique. However, if the user only changes the name field and not the e-mail field, you do not want a validation error to be thrown because the user is already the owner of the e-mail address.
>
> To instruct the validator to ignore the user's ID, we'll use the Rule class to fluently define the rule. In this example, we'll also specify the validation rules as an array instead of using the | character to delimit the rules:

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

Validator::make($data, [
    'email' => [
        'required',
        Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id),
    ],
]);
```